# Design Pattern for Module that continuously checks if other modules in the system are working?

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture, publish-subscribe, polling

I am implementing a java project where there are multiple decoupled modules interacting with a shared service (database/web service).

There is a health checker module that continuously polls all the modules to see if they are functioning or not. If a module is found to be inactive or not functioning properly, the health checker module performs a repair and restarts it.

Which behavioral pattern would this belong to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Health Checker* should basically keep track of all how the other *modules* work.

So the health checker can be an observe for changes and hence you can go with **Observer Design Pattern**. The modules should contain a method which should notify the **Health Checker** everytime there is a change.

To keep the shared resource in control you can use **Resource Management Design Pattern** or **Singleton Design Pattern**.

You can also read this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589789.aspx) Blog which discusses a similar kind of application you are talking about.

Another similar design pattern can be [this](http://www.marco.panizza.name/dispenseTM/slides/exerc/eventNotifier/eventNotifier.html).

Comment: Not sure that Observer is right here.  I think the Observer pattern is where a module notifies the observers, while here the health checker is polling the other modules, not waiting to be notified by them.

Comment: @ajb. Yes. My bad. Changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend observer in this case. In case when you have no notifications you can't differentiate between broken module and working module which does not create events.

Healthchecker should use scheduler and poll every module once in a while.
It is both easier to write and works better.